# Using buttons to switch views

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, view, switch-statement

I have a main view with four buttons, each time a button is clicked a subview is added. But when I click the button, and the subview comes up, I can´t pressed any of the other buttons. Does anyone have any suggestions? Here´s the code when a buttons is clicked:

```
newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25,25,50,20)];
[newView addSubview: testArena.view];
[newView setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 480.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)]; 
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateArenaView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
[newView setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 20.0f, 320.0f, 460.0f)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[newView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view addSubview: newView];
```

Where newView is a UIView, and testArena.view is the class I´m getting the view I want displayed from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like newView might be hiding/stopping the buttons from being pressed? Try sending it to the back, so it can't cover the buttons:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:newView];
```

Comment: Yeah, that´s what I thought too, that newView covers the buttons somehow. I tried putting [self.view sendSubviewToBack:newView]; in loadView and my action method. Still doesn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

while you click on one button inside that you can disable all other buttons..

if(button1){
button2 userinteraction enable = no;
button3 userinteraction enable = no;
button4 userinteraction enable = no;
}
if(button2){
button1 userinteraction enable = no;
button3 userinteraction enable = no;
button4 userinteraction enable = no;
}
...
..